# Trouble understanding Python `class` implementing doubly-linked-list

Tags: python, doubly-linked-list

What does `self.left.PrintTree()` mean and how come we only put `print(self.data)` only on the left one?. I'm having a huge trouble finding out the reason.. It would be nice if anyone could explain.

```py
class Node:
    
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.data = data
        
    #def Print_Tree(self) : 
        #print(self.data) 
        
    
    def insert(self, data) : 
        if self.data :
            if data < self.data : 
                if self.left is None : 
                    self.left = Node(data) 
                else :
                    self.left.insert(data)
            elif data > self.data:
                if self.right is None:
                    self.right = Node(data)
                else :
                    self.right.insert(data)
        else :
            self.data = data 
            
    def PrintTree(self) : 
        if self.left :
            self.left.PrintTree()
        print(self.data)
        if self.right  : 
            self.right.PrintTree()
      

root = Node(12)
root.insert(6)
root.insert(14)
root.insert(3)
root.PrintTree()
```

Output:

```
3
6
12
14
```

Comment: `self.left.PrintTree()` gets `left node` and run `PrintTree` for values in this `left node`

Comment: `print( self.data )` doesn't run on `left node` but on `current node`. This code first print all values in `left node`, next value in `current node`, and next all values in `right node`.